# Why put negative into unsigned integer column but didn't get the maximum value of column type?

Tags: mysql, sql

please see mysql documentation, [11.1.7 Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> If the result of **such an operation** is used to update an UNSIGNED integer column, the result is **clipped to the maximum value for the column type**, or clipped to 0 if NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION is enabled.

Through my test, I know that store 0 to unsigned column after enable "NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION".

But, what does **the operation** means? Just like the doc said: `Subtraction between integer values, where one is of type UNSIGNED, produces an unsigned result by default.`?

Following is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `uti` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT NULL
);
```

And then, `SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';`

Now, insert something.

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`uti`) VALUES (-2);
INSERT INTO `test` (`uti`) VALUES ((SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1));
```

Then, appear two `0` in the table, yeah, as was expected.

Then, `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';` or `SET sql_mode = '';`

Insert something again.

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`uti`) VALUES (-2);   -- Why is it 0??
INSERT INTO `test` (`uti`) VALUES ((SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1));  -- expect BIGINT out of range.
```

Why isn't it 254?? Just liking `unsigned char a = -2;` is 254 in C language.

Is my test way wrong??? Or I set wrong sql_mode?? I wanna know `the result is clipped to the maximum value for the column type` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions.

The `such an operation` means `SELECT CAST(... AS UNSIGNED)`. If no use the expression, eg. `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(negative)`, the result will be `0`.

Consider following table.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ubi` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Then, `SET sql_mode = '';`

Insert something.

```
-- ubi = 18446744073709551615
INSERT INTO test(ubi) VALUES((SELECT CAST(-1 AS UNSIGNED)));  
-- ubi = 18446744073709551614
INSERT INTO test(ubi) VALUES((SELECT CAST(-2 AS UNSIGNED)));
-- ubi = 18446744073709551613
INSERT INTO test(ubi) VALUES((SELECT CAST(-3 AS UNSIGNED)));
```

Now, modify `ubi` to `tinyint`.

And then, insert something.

```
INSERT INTO test(ubi) VALUES((SELECT CAST(-1 AS UNSIGNED)));  -- ubi = 255
INSERT INTO test(ubi) VALUES((SELECT CAST(-2 AS UNSIGNED)));  -- ubi = 255
INSERT INTO test(ubi) VALUES((SELECT CAST(-3 AS UNSIGNED)));  -- ubi = 255
```

That's meet the requirement!

> When an out-of-range value is assigned to an integer column, MySQL stores the value representing the corresponding endpoint of the column data type range.